# google drive authorize failed,how can I go back to the previous view？

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am making a iPhone program now.
When I used createAuthController to open a login view which is google provided.But if the view opened,and then I can not login (like forgot the password).how can I go back to the the previous view？There is no butten on the authorizatting view besides the login button.And I look for a callback on the google developers,But I am not found.
Please help me.   Thank you!!
forgive my poor English.

the code

```
- (GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)createAuthController
{
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authController;
authController = [[[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                                            clientID:kClientID
                                                        clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                    keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                            delegate:self
                                                           finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];
return authController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a "`finishedSelector`", which has the form of:

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
       finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                  error:(NSError *)error;
```

If things go bad with authorization (which you can tell from the "`error`" parameter passed in), you can go back to the previous screen.  If you're using a NavigationController, just pop back to the previous view controller.

Comment: Thanks ,but the problem is that if the login screen is opened and you failed to login（incorrect password）,it will not run into the finishedWithAuth.In this case,I can not go back to the previous screen because there is no button to let me go back.How can I work out the problem,please help me.

Comment: You also have a designated delegate.  What delegate methods get called in case of an error?

Comment: If the iPhone can not connect the internet,when the program run the `createAuthController`,the login screen can not be opened.In this case,the program will run into `finishedWithAuth` and the error code is -1009.But if the login screen was opened,the program will not run into `finishedWithAuth` even the error Occurred.Is there another callback function google has provided?